# Subtree matching with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am looking for an efficient way to calculate, whether one JSON-document is a subtree/subset of another one.
Given a JSON-document `a`

```json
{
    "a": {
        "a": {"aa": ["uvw", "abc"]},
        "b": {
            "ba": {
                "baa": ["none", "1"],
                "bab": ["0"]
            },
            "bb": {
                "baa": ["yyy"],
                "bab": ["some_string"]
            }
        },
        "c": {
            "ca": ["dd", "cc"],
            "cb": 2,
            "cc": "-" 
        }
    },
    "e": "abc",
    "d": 45678
}
```

and a JSON-document `b`

```json
{
    "a": {
        "a": {"aa": ["abc"]},
        "b": {
            "ba": {
                "baa": ["none"],
                "bab": ["0"]
            },
            "bb": {
                "bab": ["some_string"]
            }
        },
        "c": {
            "ca": ["cc"]
        }
    },
    "e": "abc"
}
```

I want to determine, whether `b` is a subset of `a`

As a result, I expect a single boolean (or something like `{'match': true}`) indicating that `b` is a subset of `a`.

I tried the following

```sh
.[0] as $a | .[1] as $b
| reduce ($a|paths) as $p (null; ($a|getpath($p)) as $va
| try($b|getpath($p)) as $vb
| if $va == $vb then setpath(["match"];true) else setpath(["match"];false) end)
```

but I miss a way to keep track of failed comparisons.

How can I accomplish this subtree-matching with `jq`?

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you define what you mean in words? I would interpret "subset" and "subtree" pretty differently, and neither feels entirely precise. From the shape of your example, I'm guessing you want to know if every path in `b` has a matching path in `a`, holding an entity of the same type, and furthermore if that entity is a scalar, then both elements have the same value?

Comment: Okay no I don't even think that's what you're asking... Do you consider `["a", "b", "c"]` to be a subset of `["c", "b", "a"]`? Is `["a", "a", "a"]` a subset of `["a"]`? How do you compare complex array members? Is `[{"red":1},{"green":1},{"blue":1}]` a subset of `[{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}]`? This is a hairy problem and you need to specify it precisely.

Comment: @Jeremy - Your document `a` is not quite right: the second "ba" under .a.b should be "bb".

Comment: @Weeble Thank you for pointing this out. Actually, I would consider `["a", "b", "c"]` and `["c", "b", "a"]` matching. I consider `["a", "a", "a"]` _not_ a subset of  `["a"]` (the reversed test should considered true, however). 
I think complex array members are out of scope here, although I am looking for the most general solution.

Comment: @peak Thanks for pointing this out. Actually, this stemmed from a little slackness, sorry for that! It is now corrected.

Comment: Thank you. I'm asking about those examples to try to draw out unstated elements of the specification. I think you should include such a specification in the question itself. Fundamentally you need to explain _why_ one is considered a subset of another to enable generalisation.

Comment: Here's a possible specification: B is a subset of A if and only if you can transform A into B only by the following operations: 1. deleting a member of an array, 2. deleting a key (and its corresponding value) from an object, 3. re-ordering the members of an array. Is that your intent?

Comment: @Weeble This sounds complete. I was thinking of hierarchical but otherwise unordere tree datastructures. With this intuition in mind, I am referring to a subtree A of tree B as  a datastructure whose nodes are completely included in B. Does that make sense for you? (I'm restricting myself to trees, which share the same root.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @weeble pointed out, the concept of "subtree" is not so simple when arrays are involved.  In particular, the simple path-value approach to your question would not match your requirements, so the following is a bit more complex, but hopefully the layout and nomenclature will help clarify things.

First, some helper functions:

```
def max(s): reduce s as $x (0; if . == null or $x > . then $x else . end);

def elementOf($x):
  . as $in
  | if ($x|type) == "array"
    then $x|index($in)
    else false end;

# drill down
def shift($n):
  if $n == 0 then .
  elif type | (. != "object" and . != "array") then empty
  elif $n == 1 then .[]
  else .[] | shift($n - 1)
  end;
```

Next, the main function, which defines a (recursive) subfunction to handle
the relatively straightforward case:

```
def subtree_of($b):
  def isScalar: type | . != "array" and . != "object";

  # direct_subtree_of($b) checks that every path/atomic-value pair of $a is also in $b
  def direct_subtree_of($b):
    . as $a
    | first( ($a|paths(scalars)) as $p
        | ($a | getpath($p)) as $va
        | ([try ($b|getpath($p)) // empty]) as $vb
        | if ($vb |length > 0) 
             and (($va == $vb[0])
                  or ($va | subtree_of($vb[0]))
                  or ($va | elementOf($b | getpath( $p[:-1] ))))
          then empty
          else 0
          end) // 1
      | . == 1 ;
    
  . as $a
  | if isScalar then $a == $b
    else direct_subtree_of($b)
         or (max($a|paths|length) as $ma
            | max($b|paths|length) as $mb
            | ($mb - $ma) as $diff
            | any(range(1; 1+$diff);
                  any(. as $i | $a | subtree_of($b | shift($i)); . )) )
    end ;
```

After correcting your `a`:

```
a | subtree_of(b)
```

evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for you great answer!
I tried it and extended you script to return the result as a JSON in the form of `{"match": true}`. However, I have an additional inquiry: Do you have a suggestion on how to calculate the result without the use of `debug`? I intend to call the jq-script to perform the subtree-matching from a program Python via its jq-bindings (to speed it up, since my Python implementation is rather slow). In my tests the script provided by you does not work due to the produced debug-output. (Actually an issue of the python-bindings I assume)
Do you have any help on this?

Comment: @Jeremy - Please note that I just uploaded a new version with a bug fix, and minus the debug statements.  It's (almost always) safe simply to remove them.

Comment: Hmmm. This makes `["b","b","b"]` a subset of `["a","b","b"]`, which again raises the question, what is the specification? I suspect that each member of the subset's array must correspond to a single member of the superset's array, and that no two members of the subset's array may use the same element of the superset's. I also have a feeling that if we don't constrain arrays to contain only scalars the problem might be NP-complete.

Comment: @Weeble Thinking of JSON-documents as hierarchical trees, then `["b","b","b"]` should not be considered matching `["a","b","b"]`, since the structure of the leafs hanging below the parent-node (the array) is different. The specification should be formulated, as you proposed: "each member of the subset's array must correspond to a single member of the superset's array". 

Actually, I think, I can live with constraining the arrays to contain only scalars. Thanks for bringing this issue up.

Comment: (Re: NP-completeness. I apologise: I'm misremembering and muddling my theory. I should instead say I suspect there may not be a worst-case polynomial time algorithm, assuming we allow non-scalar arrays. It can't be NP-complete because the answer is a boolean and cannot be verified other than by answering the problem.)

Comment: @Weeble - I think we're on the same page w.r.t. the potential for confusion regarding "subset/subtree/matching" but as far as the jq program presented here is concerned, I think it can pretty much serve as its own specification. In particular, as far as arrays are concerned, I'd like to point to the criterion: `($va | elementOf($b | getpath( $p[:-1] )))`

Comment: @peak Could you explain what the `getpath( $p[-1])` is doing here?

Comment: @Jeremy - $p holds the full array-path (in this case, to the item within an array); so in this case getpath($p[-1]) is the containing array.